# changing permission not permitted

Tags: permissions

I have this directory

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root       4096 May  3 21:06 tmp
```

I'm the user "jenkins", and I try:

```
chmod -R a+rwx tmp/
```

But I get

```
 chmod: changing permissions of `tmp/': Operation not permitted
```

why? jenkins also belong to group "wheel"...I don't understand why I can't change permission on the directory

Comment: Are you in the root directory as you execute this (so `/tmp/` is the same as `tmp/`)? If so, the answer is: because you aren't the owner of the directory.

Comment: Unrelated, but if this is `/tmp` then the directory is missing the "sticky" bit (there is no `t` in the permissions).  Correct this by doing `sudo chmod +t /tmp`.

Answer (score 5):

Only the owner of the directory, *root*, can change its permissions, allowing or not  other users to use this directory (note that *root*, as the superuser, can anyway change permissions of quite anything, owner or not).

If user *jenkins* is in the *wheel* group, this might mean, depending on the exact OS, that user *jenkins* is allowed to use `su` or `sudo` (eg: [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-gaining_privileges-the_sudo_command)) to temporarily become *root*. So this, perhaps needing *jenkins*' password, should work:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx tmp/
```

or else (needing *root*'s password):

```
su -c 'chmod -R a+rwx tmp/'
```

Being in the group *wheel*, if treated in a special way by your OS, doesn't give any direct permission. It grants the right to execute things as *root* (or other users) using various mechanisms intended for this effect (like `su` and `sudo` above), not directly.

Comment: Urgh! You beat me!  **+1**

Answer (score 5):

In human terms: you're trying to change property which isn't yours: regardless of whether you're `jenkins` in group `wheel` or not, you're trying to change the ownership of `root` in group  `root` so you cannot do that.

You can try [`sudo make me a sandwich`](https://xkcd.com/149/):

```
sudo chmod --recursive a+rwx /tmp
```

## but you shouldn't!

#### because everyone *already has these rights* in `/tmp`!

(note: `/tmp`, **not**  `tmp/`)

Comment: You made advanced research on xkcd (+1), delaying the answer! more seriously, considering the `tmp/` dir is not +t, I doubt it's `/tmp` (and hem, it shouldn't have been edited so in OP)

Comment: @A.B Rolled back to revision 1...  **0:-)**

Comment: Echo... +1 for the [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/149/) :)